# How do you make nodes automatically publish one by one after specific time?

Tags: views, nodes

I'm going to do a comic site. I saw the MemeCenter. It automatically publish comics after 10 minutes. Is there a module to do this on Drupal?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) module with rules scheduler, check this [tutorial](http://nodeone.se/sv/node/770) for better understanding on how to configure.

and also take a look at [Scheduler](https://drupal.org/project/scheduler) module